# ServiceStack CredentialsAuthProvider is ignore rememberMe = false

Tags: servicestack

I am using CredentialsAuthProvider with SS v4.0.39, and have been for well over a year.  A client has asked what the "remember me" checkbox on the login page does.  My understanding **was** that this determines whether the user's session is persisted across browser tabs.

However, having tested it, when rememberMe = false, the ss-pid cookie is still returned, and if I open other tabs/browser windows, the session is retrieved and user is an "authenticated" user.

Have I mis-understood the behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of ServiceStack `ss-id` and `ss-pid` Session Cookies are always created. The `?RememberMe=true` parameter indicates that the Users Session should be stored under the permanent Id `ss-pid` instead of the default Temporary Session Id `ss-id` which is how Users Sessions can survive Browser restarts since the `ss-pid` permanent Cookie isn't reset.

Comment: Thanks, so is the behaviour I am seeing correct? - i.e. I set "remember me"  to false, but I can still open other tabs?  Perhaps I should clear the ss-pid cookie on log out.

Comment: @Gumzle Yes, browsers use the same session cookies for all browser tabs unless you open a private/incognito browser tab. The difference is that `ss-pid` survives browser restarts whilst `ss-id` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks - I will go and download "browsers for dummies" :)